# Spock and internal kotlin function

Tags: kotlin, spock

I am having trouble with using internal kotlin functions in my Spock tests. Here's short snippet of my spock test:

```
private def preconditions = new MonetaryPreconditions()
private def usdMonetary = new Monetary(BigDecimal.ZERO, Currency.USD)

def "should throw nothing because Monetaries currencies are same"(){
    when:
    preconditions.checkMonetariesCurrencies(usdMonetary , usdMonetary )
    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
}
```

and my MonetaryPreconditions class:

```
internal object MonetaryPreconditions {

  internal fun checkMonetariesCurrencies(monetary1: Monetary, monetary2: Monetary) {
    if (monetary1.currency != monetary2.currency) {
        throw CurrencyMismatchException(arrayOf(monetary1.currency, monetary2.currency), "Compared currencies does not match: " + monetary1.currency
                + " , " + monetary2.currency)
    }
  }

}
```

My test fails with a stacktrace:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: touk.recruitment.parkandrest.parkingmanagement.core.monetary.MonetaryPreconditions.checkMonetariesCurrencies() is applicable for argument types: (touk.recruitment.parkandrest.parkingmanagement.core.monetary.Monetary, touk.recruitment.parkandrest.parkingmanagement.core.monetary.Monetary) values: [touk.recruitment.parkandrest.parkingmanagement.core.monetary.Monetary@7c417213, ...]

The problem lies in internal visibility of my checkMonetariesCurrencies function. If I change it to public it works just fine, however I do want this to be module private. How can I achieve that with Spock?

Other information about my project:

- Test class and MonetaryPreconditions have same package.
- I am using Maven.
- Test class and MonetaryPreconditions  are of course in the same module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue, and the workaround I used (suggested by an experienced coworker of mine) was to write a wrapper class in Kotlin (in the same package as the class under test (CUT); I placed the source code file in the `test/kotlin` folder) and just forward function calls to the CUT. I then used the wrapper class in my groovy unit test code.

Further, calling functions defined within an `object` in Kotlin from another programming language requires you to access the object's `INSTANCE` variable, e.g.

```
MonetaryPreconditions.INSTANCE.myfunction
```

In your case, the wrapper may look as follows:

```
package com.yourpackage

object MonetaryPreconditionsWrapper{
    fun checkMonetariesCurrencies(monetary1: Monetary, monetary2: Monetary){
        MonetaryPreconditions.checkMonetariesCurrencies(monetary1, monetary2)
    }
}
```

Now you can test the `MonetaryPreconditions.checkMonetariesCurrencies` function by simply calling the wrapper function from the groovy code as follows:

```
MonetaryPreconditionsWrapper.INSTANCE.checkMonetariesCurrencies(monetary1, monetary2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you Giuseppe for your answer. However for me, Spock didn't see the wrapper as it thought it was a property of the test class and threw a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`. I had add this to build.gradle:

```
compileTestGroovy.classpath += files(compileTestKotlin.destinationDir)
```

Taken from here: https://localcoder.org/test-classes-in-groovy-dont-see-test-classes-in-kotlin